# checking an object property when adding to Array - ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a simple algorithm problem but couldn't find a proper solution. There is an array and I just want to add an item in the array if the property of `recipe_id` is not the same in any objects `recipe_id` property value in the Array.

I want to prevent any item to add if it has the same property value. If the value of the property is different then it is ok. Thus all the objects in the Recipes array should have different `recipe_id` values. I write these code but it seems it's not working correctly

here is JSBin link : [link](https://jsbin.com/fecerezoze/1/edit?js,console)

```
   const Recipes =[
  {recipe_id:4},
  {recipe_id:5}
]

onClickedHandler = (recipe_id) => {

            const favData = {
                recipe_id: recipe_id,
            }
            if (Recipes.length > 0) {
                for (let item in Recipes) {
                    if (Recipes[item].recipe_id !== recipe_id) {
                        console.log("added in the loop!")
                        Recipes.push(item)

                    } else {
                        console.log("it is already in the Recipe list!")
                    }
                }
            } else {
              console.log("Recipes is empty")
                 Recipes.push({recipe_id:recipe_id})
            }

    }
  onClickedHandler(9)
  console.log(Recipes.length)
```

Comment: _"I write these code but it seems it's not working correctly"_ - Please add an explanation on why you think it _doesn't work_ and most importantly what does _"doesn't work"_ mean exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method to check if the ID exists in the array.
You probably need something like:

```js
const Recipes =[
 {recipe_id:4},
 {recipe_id:5}
];

function addRecipe(recipeId) {
  if(!Recipes.some(item => item.recipe_id === recipeId)) {
    Recipes.push({recipe_id:recipeId});
    console.log("Not duplicate, inserted");
  } else {
    console.log("duplicate");
  }
}

addRecipe(4);
addRecipe(6);
console.log(Recipes)
```

Comment: You did it with "find" in the first version of this post right? It works correctly, many thanks, short and simple.

Comment: Yes, I used `find`, but `some` returns a boolean so is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're going through elements, and first item when you're adding an element with id of 4 there is one item with that ID.

It doesn't pass, next iteration, it checks agains the element with different ID. It passes and goes to ID.

You need a loop within a loop, for example try .filter function, if it returns undefined, you can add it, otherwise don't add.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are pushing an object with new recipe whenever you find another object with a different id instead of checking all of them before adding.

if you were to try adding another object with id 7 (onClickedHandler(7)) after all of your code you would end up with 3 different objects with id 7

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are not returning in your `for` loop. Of course, it will iterate over all items and, **for each** item that has different `recipe_id`, it will append a new item. You should jump out your function once you find the recipe is already there:

```
for (let item in Recipes) {  // Iterate over each item (no need to test length)
    if (Recipes[item].recipe_id !== recipe_id) { // Break if recipe already there.
        console.log("it is already in the Recipe list!");
        return;
    }
}

// Otherwise, it is safe to append the recipe_id:
Recipes.push({recipe_id:recipe_id});
console.log("added in the loop!");
```

Now, when you find the same `recipe_id`, you exit from your function.